# dbus c crashed in dbus_timeout_handle

Tags: dbus

I am using dbus api for our IPC not using gdbus, since we wanted a light version of dbus. I have implemented the event loop and time out. Iam facing strange situation.

EventLoop thread is taking care of dispatching events and notifying watches.
    When Timeout has expired, the callback is called from TimerThread.

Inside the timerout expired callback, dbus_timeout_handle is called.
    The dbus_timeout_handle is waiting for connection lock, which is 
    acquired by dbus_connection_send_with_reply_and_block and removed the 
    timeout.

The dbus_timout_handle, tries to free the DBUSTimeout object resulting in memory corruption.

Kindly let me know your suggestions.

```
void Init( DBusConnection *connection )
{
    dbus_connection_set_watch_functions( connection, AddWatch, RemoveWatch, ToggleWatch, NULL, NULL );
    dbus_connection_set_timeout_functions( connection, AddTimeOut, RemoveTimeOut, ToggleTimeOut, NULL, NULL );

    dbus_connection_set_dispatch_status_function( connection, DispatchStatus, NULL, NULL );

    dbus_connection_set_wakeup_main_function( connection, WakeUp, NULL, NULL );
}


Function A()
{
    dbus_connection_send_with_reply_and_block()
}
```